# Giving MAC address to the IT dept

Tags: ip, mac-address

If I want to use Public wireless at work place with my iPhone, I must give the phones MAC address to the IT department.

Is it recommended to do so? What can they access with the MAC address? All my passwords to websites? All browsing history? or just how much data usage I have?

Comment: Please show a little effort and do a bit of research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address.  They need your MAC address because they are using it to filter who can connect.  Really though, if you don't trust the IT Dept, then don't use their network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mac address is just the unique number of your WIFI card in your phone. It contains no information about you. They can, at most, figure out what manufacturer made the device and the date it was made.

That being said, once you are connected to their wifi, then they can see where you browse to and whatnot. This is the similar to if you connected to Starbuck's wifi so probably not much to worry about.

Comment: So it will be browsing history while I am at their Wifi? So When I come home and browse somewhere else on my wifi, then still they can see those too?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark Them seeing where you browse to while on their WiFi has (practically) nothing to do with your MAC address.

Comment: They could see, if they really wanted to, what sites you are browsing while you are on their wifi. They won't be able to see passwords, browser history, or anything scary. Even your status updates you tap into facebook will be all encrypted. Stay off the nudie sites. And respect any policies they may have... often times they ask that you don't stream music or watch streaming video since it will directly affect their bandwidth, for instance.